zipkin docker container log settins
I wonder how to set logger of zipkin docker container itself like rolling policy and log level.
I tried to set log zipkin container itself.
In doc, Zipkn use spring boot. and it said i can easily set logger with docker-compose.
I can save log to specific folder. But rolling policy doesn't work.
I tried docker-compose env setting, logback.xml and command
here is logback.xml. I used volume mount to set logger.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- Rollover every minute -->
                <fileNamePattern>/workspace/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- Keep logs for 60 minutes -->
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>

here is example of my docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    user: "root"
    command: >
      java -jar zipkin.jar
      --logging.level.zipkin=DEBUG
      --logging.exception-conversion-word=%wEx{full}
      --logging.file.path=/workspace/logs
      --logging.file.name=zipkin.log
    volumes:
      - /path/to/host/log/directory:/workspace/logs
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"

